# reading in data from a text file correctly into a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text

I want to read in a text file to a 2D numpy array that has column and row labels. The text file is created from the same numpy array, so it is the same size.
This is the code I used for the array.

```
seating_chart = np.full((15, 4), '.')
```

#then I added this to name the columns and rows

```
index_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]   
column_values = ['1', '2', '3','4']   
seating_chart = pd.DataFrame(data = seating_chart,  
              index = index_values,  
              columns = column_values)
```

print(seating_chart)
#when it is printed it looks like this (nice!):

[image: labeled numpy array]

#To get the text file I want to add to this there is some input and loops I don't need to ad for #this question, then:

```
 with open('seating_chart.txt', "w") as f:
     f.write('\n'.join(''.join(elements) for elements in seating_chart))
     f.close()
```

#this provides me with a text file that looks like this(depending on the input)
[image: text file from input]

#now, i can display it this way just fine with a simple read and print function, but I would rather be able to read this text file into the numpy array and have it print with the column and row labels and the spacing.
I have tried a couple different numpy text functions, if you have any ideas as to what is the correct numpy text function to use I would appreciate it. I tried these from kite.com. https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-load-a-text-file-to-a-numpy-array-of-strings-in-python
thank you!

Ok, i have an update. I tried making a dataframe in pandas, and it worked okay, but went back to numpy for the array because I think it works better. i did use pandas  to read the text file into the numpy array, and it is close. i just can't seen to split the "...." into ['.','.','.','.'] after joining it when the data is added. so i may see if i can write the original file to a list and use that list in pandas instead of the joined text file. i could write another text file, but i want to limit it to one. if anyone knows how to split this string for a pandas function i would appreciate the info.

```
def display():
    df = pd.read_csv('seating_chart.txt', names=[1, 2, 3, 4])
    df.index = np.arange(1, len(df)+1)
    print(df)
```

this gives me:it looks good, once i get it split I will be done with that part. I am pretty new to coding, but am enjoying figuring these things out.
[image: almost there seating chart display]

Comment: There is no single "numpy text function"; you have to learn the input/output methods, and program your own.  So far, you're doing fine.  I question whether you need NumPy -- PANDAS should be able to do your seating chart as well, and has better I/O methods.  Consider keeping your file in a format friendlier to your data structure; text is only if you must have the file in human-readable form.

Comment: ok, thanks. I considered using pandas, i will look at that closer, but didn't want to get into reworking all of my code, it is a fairly large program. I have to have the output in text unfortunately.

Comment: Ah.  Given those qualities (need text, large program), you likely want to encapsulate your input and output routines, and make the internal manipulation coded in whatever form best supports your business operations..